# Manual swiping in view pager using Trinea/android-auto-scroll-view-pager is not working?

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, autoscroll

I am using third party library for automatic scrolling and touch events in an image slider every thing is working fine except manual swiping of images in image slider. I am not able to swipe images manually.
Name of the library which I am using is 
"Trinea/android-auto-scroll-view-pager"

Here is my code for fragment where Ii am using auto scroll view pager:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
    TextView tv_slider, tv_button;
    AutoScrollViewPager mViewPager;



    private static int currentPage = 0;
    private static int NUM_PAGES = 0;
    private static final Integer[] IMAGES= {R.drawable.ecommerce, R.drawable.digital_marketing, R.drawable.explainer, R.drawable.it_services,
            R.drawable.mobile_app, R.drawable.seo, R.drawable.software, R.drawable.webdesign};
    private ArrayList<Integer> ImagesArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();


    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public HomeFragment() {

    }

    public static HomeFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);


        }
    }




    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        tv_slider=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tv_slider);
        tv_slider.setTypeface(EasyFonts.robotoLight(this.getActivity()));
        tv_button=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tv_button);
        tv_button.setTypeface(EasyFonts.robotoLight(this.getActivity()));



        for(int i=0;i<IMAGES.length;i++)
            ImagesArray.add(IMAGES[i]);



        mViewPager = (AutoScrollViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(new SlidingImage_Adapter(getActivity(),ImagesArray));
        mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);


        CirclePageIndicator indicator = (CirclePageIndicator)
                v.findViewById(R.id.indicator);

        indicator.setViewPager(mViewPager);

        final float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

//Set circle indicator radius
        indicator.setRadius(3 * density);

        NUM_PAGES =IMAGES.length;

        mViewPager.startAutoScroll();
        mViewPager.setInterval(3000);

        mViewPager.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

                switch(motionEvent.getAction())
                {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        Log.w("touched","down");
                        mViewPager.stopAutoScroll();
                        return true;
                    //break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        Log.w("touched","up");
                        mViewPager.startAutoScroll();
                        return true;

                }



                return true;
            }
        });





        // Pager listener over indicator
        indicator.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                currentPage = position;

            }



            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int pos, float arg1, int arg2) {

                switch (pos){

                    case 0:
                        tv_slider.setText(getString(R.string.es_content));
                        break;

                    case 1:
                        tv_slider.setText(getString(R.string.dm_content));
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        tv_slider.setText(getString(R.string.ev_content));
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        tv_slider.setText(getString(R.string.it_content));
                        break;

                    case 4:
                        tv_slider.setText(getString(R.string.md_content));
                        break;

                    case 5:
                        tv_slider.setText(getString(R.string.seo_content));
                        break;

                    case 6:
                        tv_slider.setText(getString(R.string.sd_content));
                        break;

                    case 7:
                        tv_slider.setText(getString(R.string.wd_content));
                        break;

                }



            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int pos) {

            }
        });


        return v;


    }








    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);


    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }




    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mViewPager.startAutoScroll();
    }


    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mViewPager.stopAutoScroll();
    }
}
```

This is my adapter class:

```
public  class SlidingImage_Adapter extends PagerAdapter {


    private ArrayList<Integer> IMAGES;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context context;


    public SlidingImage_Adapter(Context context, ArrayList<Integer> IMAGES) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        this.IMAGES=IMAGES;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }



    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return IMAGES.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup view, int position) {
        View imageLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sliding_images, view, false);

        assert imageLayout != null;
        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) imageLayout
                .findViewById(R.id.image);


        imageView.setImageResource(IMAGES.get(position));

        view.addView(imageLayout, 0);

        return imageLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view.equals(object);
    }

    @Override
    public void restoreState(Parcelable state, ClassLoader loader) {
    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
        return null;
    }

}
```

This is homefragment.xml file

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/background"
    tools:context="com.vamediabox.vamediaboxapp.activities.MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    </RelativeLayout>



<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
       >



        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView

            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/rl_slider"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
            app:cardElevation="4dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
            app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">



            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:id="@+id/rl1">

            <cn.trinea.android.view.autoscrollviewpager.AutoScrollViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />



                <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
                    android:id="@+id/indicator"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/pager"
                    android:padding="5dip"
                    app:centered="true"
                    app:fillColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    app:pageColor="@color/view_color"
                    app:snap="false" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:id="@+id/tv_slider"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/indicator"
                android:textColor="@color/slider_text"

                />


            </RelativeLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
  </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and last this is sliding_images.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="1dip" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

not sure if you still looking for a way to fix this in case you do, check **consumeTouch** inside **AutoScrollViewPager** this is where your issue is.

You need to make sure that

```
getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)
```

is getting called.

hope this helps.

Cheers